# UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN:Domain not whitelisted by project Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, email, oauth

I am developing an application in which I want to authenticate (login), via email without a password.
I didn't get much current documentation on this, so I took the example of the Firebase itself on GitHub.

The problem is that, when I'm going to put the email, it returns an error in my Log:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN: Domain not whitelisted by project ]
```

I already researched a lot about this error, and what they answer is that the domains need to be updated.

I don't have a paid domain, so I'm using the ones generated by Firebase itself.

The encodings are as follows:

Android Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="https://telefones-c6ce7.web.app/"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                android:host="http://telefones-c6ce7.web.app/"
                android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.firebaseapp.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.firebaseapp.com"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.web.app"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="telefones-c6ce7.web.app"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:scheme="http"/>

                <data
                    android:host="https://a0800restinga.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="http://a0800restinga.page.link"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

See that I put several domain links that I found interesting to do tests.

At the click of my button, it has the following code:

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
                ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                        // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                        // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                        .setUrl(url)
                        // This must be true
                        .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                        .setAndroidPackageName(
                                "com.joel.a0800restinga",
                                true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                                "1.2.6"    /* minimumVersion */)
                        .setDynamicLinkDomain("a0800restinga.page.link")
                        .build();

        firebaseAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "email? " + email);
                        //Void v = task.getResult();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "void is " + v);
                        boolean emailWasSent = task.isSuccessful();
                        if (emailWasSent) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                        } else {
                            Exception e = task.getException();
                            Log.d(TAG, "There was a problem");
                            Log.e(TAG, "msg ", e);
                        }
                        setText(emailWasSent);
                    }
                });
```

In which, the seturl I am generating, and it directs correctly as I have already analyzed in the click.
I believe that the other information is correct.

Finally, I already included the SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys in my project and inserted the JSON in the application.

I am testing everything via emulator.

In my Firebase settings, I have dynamic links, and all are valid:
[image]

In authentications I have only this asset:
[image]

And these are the authorized domains:

[image]

Comment: Firebase allows you to authenticate via email confirmation without the need to create a password.
I want to use this option precisely to have documented via email that the user registered in my app. Would it have a better shape? For example an email confirmation before allowing access to the application? Because that is exactly what firebase does, until you click on the activation link, there is no permission to access the application

Comment: I see you are referring to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth). In this case, once you are successfully authenticated, inside onComplete, do the logic that you need. Not before, as Firebase API is asynchronous.

Comment: this is the real problem. Within onComplete, the exception occurs on the line

boolean emailWasSent = task.isSuccessful ();
                        if (emailWasSent) {

therefore, did not get to validate